# How to get recent added three data FROM SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to get Last three data from SQLite

i have already Query for Getting all data from SQLite database date and time wise

but i want to get last three data **Query is**

```
List<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<Company>();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + COMPANY + " ORDER BY (" + KEY_CREATED_AT + ") DESC " ;
```

Hear i am getting the data:

```
companyList = myComDb.getAllCompany();
        companiesAdapter = new CompaniesAdapter(companyList);
        companiesAdapter.setClickListener(companyListItemClickListner);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        rvCompanies.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager1);
        rvCompanies.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvCompanies.setAdapter(companiesAdapter);
```

**i want to just get Recent added 3 data**

Comment: just use limit in query

Comment: You already have created date field . Just use limit with order by created date desc.

Comment: Can any other Technic to get three data like using for loop or anything
If i getting all data and all this for loop **`List<Company> companyList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = companyList.size()-1; i>companyList.size()-4; i-- ) {
            companyList1.add(companyList.get(i));`** 1st time it's getting 3 data but now this not work @ADM

Comment: Sqlite does not ensure insertion ordering . So ultimately you have to use order by whether you use a loop or a limit . Using limit is right solution .all result will loaded in just single query. If you want to get next 3 data in next call use keyword OFFSET . Look into sqlite documentation .

Comment: ok but in 1 activity i want to get 3 data and 2nd activity i'll get all data then i'll use 2 Query so code is large so i am telling you if other solution @ADM

Comment: You can keep it that way . Loading all data is never a good solution . Load data in chunks (if its huge) with pagination with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit` in your query which will return the `n` (`n` is the number of the row you want to fetch) row.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + COMPANY + " ORDER BY (" + KEY_CREATED_AT + ") DESC LIMIT 3 " ;
```

Comment: Can any other Technic to get three data like using for loop or anything ?
if i getting all data and add for loop for getting last three data like this **`List<Company> companyList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = companyList.size()-1; i>companyList.size()-4; i-- ) {
            companyList1.add(companyList.get(i));`** 1st time it's getting but now it's not work so how to i get using for loop

Comment: @MohammadAli  If you get the all the 3 rows at a time then you have the list of List<Company>. I am not sure why you are iterating over companyList and also what is the content of the company list? `companyList`? Is it containing the query result?

Comment: u can suggest me using `limite 3` i'll getting 3 data i understand and it's use full 
but same thing i am getting data using for loop @AmitBera